# vim won't open with plugins installed the pathogen way

Tags: vim

I recently found out about vim-pathogen, and installing vim plugins on my Mac has been working great. I tried using vim-pathogen on an external Linux cluster, but as soon as I clone a plugin repository into the `.vim/bundle` directory, I suddenly can't even open vim. A copy of my session is shown below. How do I fix this?

```
lindsb@rrlogin:~$ ls .vim
lindsb@rrlogin:~$ cat .vimrc
lindsb@rrlogin:~$ mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle && \
> curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim
lindsb@rrlogin:~$ ls .vim/*
.vim/autoload:
pathogen.vim

.vim/bundle:
lindsb@rrlogin:~$ echo -e "execute pathogen#infect()\nsyntax on\nfiletype plugin indent on" > .vimrc
lindsb@rrlogin:~$ cat .vimrc
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
lindsb@rrlogin:~$ vi
lindsb@rrlogin:~$ git clone https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose .vim/bundle/vim-autoclose
Cloning into '.vim/bundle/vim-autoclose'...
remote: Counting objects: 326, done.
remote: Total 326 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 326 
Receiving objects: 100% (326/326), 97.85 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (132/132), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
lindsb@rrlogin:~$ ls .vim/*
.vim/autoload:
pathogen.vim

.vim/bundle:
vim-autoclose
lindsb@rrlogin:~$ vi
*** glibc detected *** vim: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000197ee800 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x326da714af]
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4b)[0x326da757ab]
vim(clear_tv+0x4e)[0x453c7e]
|      |      |
|      |      |
V      V      V
[ a bunch more lines of similar error output ]
```

I'm not savvy enough to learn much of anything from the error output

Comment: There is an SO site dedicated to vi and vim. You might get an answer there sooner. The only thing I can suggest is try with a different plugin. That should tell you if the problem is with the autoclose plugin or not.

Comment: @Bram Didn't know that, I'll try my luck there. I did try with other plugins and got the same result. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reposted [my issue](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5256/vim-wont-open-if-execute-pathogeninfect-in-vimrc/5263#5263) on the Vi and Vim Beta site and figured out the problem with the help of [Christian Brabandt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/71/christian-brabandt). For the sake of completeness, my issue was caused by an old version of vim. I installed locally by cloning the [vim git repo](https://github.com/vim/vim.git) then executing `./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr/vim && make && make install` within the top directory of the vim repo. (`$HOME/usr/vim` is where I wanted vim installed) The new vim worked great with the pathogen plugin installation method, but it opened really slowly. By analyzing the startup time with `vim --startuptime out.log` I found that setting up the clipboard was taking up most of the startup time. Following the instructions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635295/vim-takes-a-very-long-time-to-start-up) I found that `vim -X` opened much faster, so I added `set clipboard=exclude:.*` to my `.vimrc` file. Now everything works great.